# How can I access the raw data from individual data frame cells using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working on a custom elo/team rating calculator using a CSV file as input. I was able to get similar logic for this working in Excel with openpyxl but I am now trying to implement it in pandas for better integration with jupyter and matplotlib. I'm having issues running calculations on individual cells in the data frames, however.

```
def find_team_row(team_name):
    switcher = {
        '100T': 0,
        'C9': 1,
        'CG': 2,
        'CLG': 3,
        'FOX': 4,
        'FLY': 5,
        'GGS': 6,
        'OPT': 7,
        'TL': 8,
        'TSM': 9,
    }
    return switcher.get(team_name, None)

def update_df():
    for column in range(1, df.columns.get_loc(df.columns[-1]), 3):
        for row in range(0,9):

            init_rating = df.iloc[row,column]
            opponent_name = df.iloc[row,column+1]
            match_result = df.iloc[row,column+2]
            oppo_rating = df.iloc[find_team_row(opponent_name),column]
```

These exceptions are thrown with respect to this code block:

```
ajisaksonmac:elo_calc ajisakson$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 "/Users/ajisakson/Google Drive/swe_projects/elo_calc/test2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 235, in _has_valid_tuple
    self._validate_key(k, i)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2035, in _validate_key
    "a [{types}]".format(types=self._valid_types)
ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ajisakson/Google Drive/swe_projects/elo_calc/test2.py", line 74, in <module>
    update_df()
  File "/Users/ajisakson/Google Drive/swe_projects/elo_calc/test2.py", line 27, in update_df
    oppo_rating = df.iloc[find_team_row(opponent_name),column] 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1418, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2092, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 239, in _has_valid_tuple
    "[{types}] types".format(types=self._valid_types)
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types
```

So I'm trying to access individual cells in the data frame using iloc but I receive this ValueError where oppo_rating is assigned. I tried a number of different things to convert both of the iloc parameters to integers including int(), .iat(), .at(), .loc(), etc. and I continue to receive errors suggesting that one of my parameters is not an integer.

Here is the first part of the data frame I'm trying to manipulate/make calculations on:
[example of the pandas data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYLy4.png)

Comment: please add an example for df

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYLy4.png This is the link I have at the bottom of the post of the df. I can include more if needed